# Startswith Error in Python

Tags: python, startswith

I am trying to read through a file and skip certain lines. I'm using `str.startswith()` to do this:

```
for lines in analysis:

    if line.startswith("#"):
        continue
```

Then, I have further cases that analyzes all subsequent lines.

However, I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'line' is not defined
```

Why doesn't this work...?

Comment: Did you even **read** the error? It is blindingly obvious. This has nothing to do with `startswith`.

Answer (score 4):

Simple typo. You are using `lines` in for statement, and `line` in if statement.